# Number of Images allowed in Backstretch Slideshow

Tags: jquery-backstretch

I wondered if you can add more than three images to a jQuery Backstretch slideshow, I have three images rotating but it wont pick up a fourth, see code;

```
$('document').ready(function () {
 $.backstretch([
  "images/img1.jpg"
, "images/img2.jpg"
, "images/img3.jpg"
, "images/img4.jpg"
```

], {duration: 3000, fade: 1250});

Thanks

Comment: You can def have more than 3, but I also have a random stop mid way through my slideshow.